# Using flex on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, plugins, ubuntu, adobe

Pardon me if I am re-posting the same question but I am a newbie and want to learn flex. My problem is I don't know how to start with..

I work on windows machine and I searched for eclipse plugin but every where its about installing flex builder which leads me to http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/ . Firstly I don't know flex builder. what I googled and understood is flex builder will give us a user friendly environment to build flex apps. what I need is some eclipse plugin through which I can create flex projects.(By flex builder do we mean that it is essential for creating a flex project through eclipse ).

In Adobe download repo i can find sth like Open Source flex4 SDK,  wont this be sufficient for flex related development.

Thanks in advance

Comment: all links available are giving instructions as per the previously available plugin... have ubuntu + eclipse ppl seized working with flex .... :O

Comment: @Adnan : can you please help!!!!

Comment: Ok !!! finally I installed fles SDK on my ubuntu machine ...can any one please help with creating a flex project on eclipse

Comment: Not sure about a plugin, but if you are wiling you can use mxmlc : more at: http://www.dotkam.com/2009/03/29/adobe-flex-in-ubuntu-develop-compile-and-run/

Comment: OK!!! thanks Adnan ... I will do it through command line but it will be a great help if there is any eclipse plugin!! (sorry for being IDE spoilt brat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no linux version of Flash Builder.  Trust me, I even hacked one together and it was horrible.  There are however other IDEs that handle Flex like [IntelliJ Ideas](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) and [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt/download/).

As for how to start your first project, I would recommend you use google because there's ample examples already out there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no eclipse plugin for the Flash/Flexbuilder product family on Linux.  This is from the link you posted

> ```
> Adobe will no longer be investing in the development
> of a version of Adobe® Flex® Builder™ or Adobe Flash® 
> Builder™ that runs on Linux operating systems
> ```

The only option you have is to use mxmlc and compile from the command line.  Since Flex is done in ECMAScript, you may be able to use an IDE to help you but of course you lose the ability to debug, automate test and use the design view.

Comment: are there no other solution (for e.g using WINE etc ).. I am new to linux and past few months were quite exciting using linux but this is very disheartening that there is no solution currently present for running flex builder on linux...:(((